# Active record query with join and conditions on two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to do this query using active record so I can make the query safe from injection. DB is Postgresql. Ruby on Rails 3.2.11

```
 def find_possible_duplicates(last_name, date_of_birth, organisation_id)
    find_by_sql( 'select c.* from clients c' +
                 ' join locations l on c.location_id = l.id' +
                 " where c.last_name ILIKE #{last_name}" +
                 " and c.date_of_birth = #{date_of_birth}" +
                 " and l.organisation_id = #{organisation_id}" 
 end
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the Active Record query :

```
 Client.select('clients.*').
 joins('join locations on clients.location_id=locations.id').
 where('last_name like ? and date_of_birth =? and organisation_id = ?',last_name,date_of_birth,organisation_id)
```